# Grab and manipulate user data without models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I would like to grab a user's input, pull it into my views.py, manipulate it, and then use that data in other views.

I do not need this data stored in a database, as I won't be referencing it again, and I want to keep this as lightweight as possible.

Currently, I'm trying to pull data from espn's fantasy football site using the python library espnff. My homepage consists of a textfield box and a submit button (Think of google.com).

I have functions set up that will comb through an espn url such as http://games.espn.com/ffl/clubhouse?leagueId=123456 to grab the leagueID, from there I make use of espnff to grab more info on that league.

My ideal use case is someone comes to my site, copies and pastes their league url like the one above, clicks submit and then brings them to https://example.com/{{ leagueID}/ which will display different info that I gather.

I have not found a way to do this without submitting the user input to a model. Is possible to avoid using the database? If so how?

Comment: you can use caching. Redis/Memcache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood it right, but what you are trying to do can easily be done without using any models/database or any other kind of persistent storage.

The user submits that information using the form, you grab the URL from the `request` object in your view, parse the URL to get the `league_id` and then redirect the user to `/{league_id}`.

Then on that view, you gather the `league_id` parameter (from the url), use the library (`espnff`) to fetch the data with that id and then render the template with that data.

For example, the implementation would be something in these lines:

Make a form in your html template:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" name="league_url"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', index_view, name="index"),
url(r'^(?P<league_id>[0-9]+)$', league_view, name="league_view")
```

in views.py:

```
def index_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        league_url = request.POST.get('league_url', None)
        # Your code to parse the URL and extract the ID
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/{}'.format(league_id))
    else:
        # render form template

def league_view(request, league_id):
    # your code here using the league_id
    # and render the page with data
```

(I didn't tested that code, I just wrote it quickly as an example of the flow)

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. Can you provide some more detail on how to grab the url from the user input?

Comment: @ZacharyBloss done, added some snippets as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The django documentation describes quite extensively how to do caching with django. You can find the documentation on how to [set that up here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache)

Once it's been set up you simply use the cache in the following way

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set('my_key', 'my_value', 60) # number is in seconds
value = cache.get('my_key')
```

You can provide dictionaries and such as values. The caching framework will serialize that for you using pickle.